# Python quits unexpectedly after returning from function

Tags: python-3.x, macos

Running Python 3.7.9 on macOS Catalina v10.15.6. Never had this sort of issue come up. From other people, it looks like it's an issue when using libraries, however my code does not use any libraries and the file name is chessKnights.py, and it runs a recursive function that is fine for almost any values within the intended range, but breaks under certain values.

```
Error Code:
Process:               Python [1066]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.9 (3.7.9)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [1029]
Responsible:           Python [1029]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-03-13 21:48:46.408 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G73)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.6 (17P6065)
Anonymous UUID:        836E79A4-BA39-7EE8-CE6F-20327CBB8D7A


Time Awake Since Boot: 1900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Comment: Some module somewhere called `abort()`, which is a C function that aborts the process.  Given what you said, I'd guess you recursed too deep and blew off the end of the stack.  Without seeing the code, of course, none of us can do anything but guess.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tim Roberts, I went back and realized I wasn’t exiting one of my conditions properly and recursed too deep.